# What delimiter can be used for .csv that has "," in it's column

Tags: c#, .net, csv, delimiter, streamwriter

I want to read .csv file and write to other .csv file.
I use `streamwriter` and use `string.split` with `delimiter (',')`.

```
 using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(destFile, true))
            {
                  string lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
                  foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if (line != lines[0])
                        {  
                            string[] values = line.Split(',');
                            file.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}",
                                    values[43], values[0], values[11], values[12], values[13], values[15], values[14], values[28], values[22], values[9]);
 }}}
```

But, there are few column that has `,` in it's `data` such as shown below, thus producing `incorrect output` because the program has count it as the `delimiter`.

[image]

I have tried using `tinyCSVParser` library but it also using delimiter which will produce same result. When I change to `CSVHelper` library, it does not use delimiter but because the input file has column with name `public double B/S`, thus I stuck there because the properties cannot accept that name.

```
[Name("B/S")]
private double p = 0;
public double B/S
{
    get
    {
        return p;
    }
    set
    {
        double result;
        result = double.Parse(Principal) * value / Day / 100;
        p = Math.Abs(result);
    }
}
```

What should I replace the `delimiter` with?

Comment: Why do you not rename your C# property? Call it "BperS" and you're done.

Comment: They should have "double quotes".  They do.  Set [TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes?view=netcore-3.1#Microsoft_VisualBasic_FileIO_TextFieldParser_HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes) to true.

Comment: @Hans Passant , Great. I have look into it but the code is only for VB. Is it also available for C#?

Comment: Yes, .NET does not care what language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you well...

Try this:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(destFile, true))     
{
    string lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] delimiter = line==lines[0] ? new string[]{","} : new string[]{"\",\"", "\""};
        string[] values = line.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Check this out: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/duzaX0)

**Note:** if you want to split string by qoutation mark, you need to use backslash in a string. See: [How to: Put Quotation Marks in a String (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-put-quotation-marks-in-a-string-windows-forms)

Comment: what is `[lineno]` referring to? I put `line != lines[0]` to remove the header.

Comment: Sorry. Typos have been removed. See updated answer.

Comment: I think you want to create custom delimiter right? I try your code but it said `index out of range`

Comment: `index out of range` says that you're trying to access an array, where the length of array is less than used index. Check your code.

Comment: Take a look here: [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/duzaX0)

Comment: I understand that you want to show me how to set the delimiter. So, for my case, do I need to set it to `string[] delimiter = new string[] { "", "," };` ? So that it can works for both "without comma" and "with,comma".

Comment: Please, take a deep look at the code (i did provide) to find the answer. Tip: there's small difference...

Comment: I have understand how it works. But is it will automatically create the \ in the " " ? Because in my input file, It only have " " without \ . When I test it with " " a,b,c " ", it would not work.

Comment: Ohhh, i see what problem you do have... Backslash is an escape character for single quote. You need to use it with c#. See: [How to: Put Quotation Marks in a String (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-put-quotation-marks-in-a-string-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a CSV-library to write csv-file. But you can check how to format csv in  the definition [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2).

> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields.